# htaccess not working due to some mystical issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running `Windows 7 xampp server` it has `Apache` and it has lines that are needed to uncomment to work fine.

However when I try to use `RewriteRule` I bump into the problem.

When I write wrong code at the start of htaccess it throws error 500, there are few commands that works, but when I use RewriteRule it simply ignore that part , unless if I write something syntax wise wrong then it reacts as error, but i have never seen my link changed.

.htaccess file is placed at myDomain directory

Can it possibly be issue of software or it's my code?

I have this dynamic link:

```
http://localhost//myDomain/folder/ad.php?title=theTitle&id=1
```

and I need to get this:

```
http://localhost//myDomain/folder/theTitle/1
```

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myDomain/folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ad.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=(.*)&id=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/myDomain/folder/%1/%2.aspx? [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be highly honored :)

Comment: You *do* know that the rewrite is supposed to work the other way around? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: It should be placed in `/myDomain/folder/` directory (posted an answer below)

Comment: Stop living in fairyland – and look into the server’s error log, instead of twaddling about “mystical issues” …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have these rules in `/myDomain/folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myDomain/folder/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ad\.php\?title=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ad.php?title=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I will find you, and I will give you a cookie :)

Comment: Small issue fallowed up styles that was included into ad.php does not work now when I include it as separate file it does not even compile it, throws out code as it's writen

Comment: For css/js etc just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.